# Multiple antennas vs signle antenna

Tags: rf, antenna, transmitter

I have a radio transmitter (for my quadcopter) and I wanted to improve its range. So for now I removed its integrated antenna and I soldered a male sma connector so I can plug in any antenna I want. I was thinking to add one more antenna. Keep in mind that the transmitter has only one antenna. So adding a second antenna will be something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fml3iC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Basically the second antenna will be connected to the first one. I would like to know if adding the second antenna will be better, worse or simply the same.

Comment: Depends on the impedance of the antennae AFAIK - can't tell without giving us some more info about the antennas (e.g. the length of the antenna and the frequency of the radio link).

Comment: @MortenJensen 2.4GHz

Comment: It is not easy to connect two antennas to one transmitter to get a better result. It is very likely that the result will be much worse. It is especially difficult for frequencies in the GHz area. Without very sophisticated equipment and a deep insight to antenna theory, it is impossible to get a better result. The insertion of a sma connector pair and additional may impair the matching of the antenna to the transmitter.

Comment: A single antenna-with-gain will give increased apparent transmitted power **but only if you point it at your 'copter**. Otherwise, it will give less power. Too much to do (fly & point at the same time).

Comment: Need a spotter with Yagi antenna if you want longer range.

Comment: At best, it will be just as good, if we're talking about extending your range. Given that all conditions are the same and perfect, you'll split the transmitter power between the antennas, but it's still the same amount of power whether its one or multiple antennas. You will not achieve a longer range this way an will almost surely make it worse. This also ignores a plethora of other issues which some people have already addressed.

Comment: @Envidia Thanks, now I understand why adding a second antenna gonna be bad. However, replacing the integrated antenna with an sma connector and using an aftermarket antenna was a good choice or I still make things worse??

Comment: Well, if you know what you're doing and you match impedances correctly, it might be a good choice. However the specifications on integrated antennas are pretty tight compared to what someone can do at home and correctly integrating an aftermarket antenna to your project and getting good results might be near impossible. Even if you do manage to integrate the after market antenna, the performance increase (again it will probably be worse) won't be worth the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An antenna's impedance is matched to the transmission circuit in order to produce the best output level (within regulatory rules). Putting two antenna's in parallel at best shares the power. At worst, they together get half the power and even worse they may produce fields that cancel each other's transmission and you get very little transmission distance.

You might get lucky with some antennas and get an improvement but that improvement will be more directional than with a single antenna. This may prove problematic in itself because you have to be facing the quadcopter more precisely than before (and it may still break regulatory rules).

Comment: Does this mean that I shouldn't even remove the integrated antenna?

Comment: You can remove it but I wouldn't take the risk of trying to transmit without an antenna because this *might* destroy the output transistors in the power amplifier that feeds the antenna.

Comment: https://quadquestions.com/blog/2015/06/15/long-range-fpv-setup/

Comment: @Andyaka No, I removed the integrated antenna just to put an sma connector so I can use any antenna I want. Not to leave the transmitter without an antenna.